# Using max-width and min-width for a scalable design

Tags: css, mobile

I'm building a mobile website that must scale to accommodate devices between 4 inches and 6 inches. Which two values should I assign to the `min-width` and `max-width` CSS properties of my global container?

I'm looking for an answer in the format of "325px and 800px." That's just an example, though, because I'm not sure that pixels are the correct unit of measurement.

Comment: You should use a fluid/responsive layout, not fixed-width

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I expect the design to be fluid to a point, but it must stop scaling at a given minimum and maximum width. Can you think of max-width and min-width values that would (roughly) accommodate four-to-six-inch screens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally is the **resolution** of the device you need to consider, not the width and height of the physical device.

You should set the max-width to whatever is the largest size that looks good for your layout, for example: `max-width: 1200px`.

For min-width, you should try to make it essentially as small as possible and still look good. But most devices have at least resolution of 320px. So you should be ok with `min-width:320px;`

Check out this list of devices and their resolutions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density

Comment: But why set a `min-width` at all, if your assumption is a resolution of atleast 320px anyway?

Comment: If your layout is unusable below 320px because it collapses on itself in some way for example, scroll bars is better, so why not set a min-width value in that case.